# What mail daemon should I get if I'm going to run an intermediate mail server for just myself?

Tags: email, mail-server

I've heard of too many people losing things because they only had copies stored in “the cloud”. Their provider banned them, they got locked out of their account, there was some kind of legal claim…for whatever reason. I always tell people, don't rely on the cloud. Make sure YOU have copies of your stuff on machines YOU control.

Then I realized I don't take this approach at all when it comes to mail.

What I want is full control over my long-term mail storage: I don't want to have to worry about privacy or losing any of my archived messages.

My first thought was to set up an intermediate mail server on one of my own computers. This server would download inbound mail from the “real” mail servers and then delete their copies. It would also take outbound mail from my clients, save copies to a `Sent` mailbox, and forward it to the servers.

This brings me to my question: what mail daemon should I use for this? I wouldn't like to spend a ton of time setting up and maintaining it, but it doesn't have to be overly simplified either (I'm perfectly comfortable in a *nix command line environment). And is my solution even a good idea?

Currently I only really send and read mail from my Mac laptop, using OS X's bundled mail client. I am planning to get an Android phone soon, though, and maybe switch clients. The daemon doesn't need to be super-scalable: I might host mail for a couple of friends, but that'll be it. I'm also a freak about security, so TLS 1.1 or newer for everything is a must.